# jquery append() simply not working

Tags: jquery, append

I have a simple function that's supposed to show a message inside a div on a select box change:
The HTML goes like this:

```
<select id="_Room" name="Room" class="form-contro  onchange="addRoom(this.value);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
```

and the JS is as follows:

```
function addRoom(room, message) {

        $("#_messageBox").append(room);
}
```

if I replace the append() with alert(room) it works, but the append() doesn't.
Any idea why ?

Thank you

Comment: I could not find element with id _messageBoxb and please show us how you call addRoom

Comment: You're missing `"` at the end of your `class` attribute. Where is `#_messageBox`? What do you see if you `alert( $("#_messageBox").length )`? Also, what do you mean when you say this doesn't work? Is there an exception in your console? Are you not seeing what you expect to see on your page? What exactly is happening?

Comment: @adil I call it onchange()

Comment: The code works: http://jsfiddle.net/hpjde/. We'll need more information - what is it doing, or *not* doing?

Comment: @JonathanSampson I don`t see anything. #_messaBox is a div with id = "_messageBox"

Comment: @user1709251 We need to see more code - there's just too little to go on right now. Is your page online some place? Can you create a demo for us using http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

In current html block, what you showing, you need add next:

```
</select>
<span id='_messageBox'></span>
```

And more, the code

```
$("#_messageBox").append(room);
```

is added(append to exist) code in block.
Maybe best use

```
$("#_messageBox").html(room);
```

is replace HTML code in block.